# Healthcheck used for initialization of Mongodb replicaset in docker-compose

Tags: mongodb, docker-compose, dockerfile, initialization, health-check

Here is the docker-compose file with a MongoDB replica set, and I'm using a health check to initialize the set. It generally accomplishes the task, but it generates a warning on the container after some time. Could someone explain to me why the check fails? I added an OR statement ("rs.status().ok") that should work after the initialization.
(i know that healthckeck shouldn't be used for this, its for a project)

```
healthcheck:
            test: test $$(echo "rs.initiate({_id:'rs0',members:[{_id:0,host:\"mongodb1:27017\"},{_id:1,host:\"mongodb2:27018\"},{_id:2,host:\"mongodb3:27019\"}]}).ok || rs.status().ok" | mongosh --port 27017 --quiet) -eq 1
            interval: 10s
            start_period: 30s
            timeout: 60s
```

Here is only the helthckeck.

```
version: "3"

services:
    mongodb1:
        container_name: mongodb1
        image: mongo
        restart: always
        ports:
        - "27017:27017"
        command: mongod --replSet rs0 --port 27017 --bind_ip_all
        healthcheck:
            test: test $$(echo "rs.initiate({_id:'rs0',members:[{_id:0,host:\"mongodb1:27017\"},{_id:1,host:\"mongodb2:27018\"},{_id:2,host:\"mongodb3:27019\"}]}).ok || rs.status().ok" | mongosh --port 27017 --quiet) -eq 1
            interval: 10s
            start_period: 30s
            timeout: 60s
        volumes:
         - ./mongodb/db1:/data/db
        networks:
            - Internal
            
    mongodb2:
        container_name: mongodb2
        image: mongo
        restart: always
        ports:
        - "27018:27018"
        command: mongod --replSet rs0 --port 27018 --bind_ip_all
        networks:
            - Internal
        volumes:
         - ./mongodb/db2:/data/db
        depends_on:
            - mongodb1

    mongodb3:
        container_name: mongodb3
        image: mongo
        restart: always
        ports:
        - "27019:27019"
        command: mongod --replSet rs0 --port 27019 --bind_ip_all
        networks:
            - Internal 
        volumes:
         - ./mongodb/db3:/data/db
        depends_on:
            - mongodb1
    networks:
    Internal:
        internal: true
    External:
```

Here is the full docker compose file.

Answer (score 0):

After running `rs.initiate()` you have to wait a some time till replica set is initiated.

For initialization and healthckeck I would suggest a script like this:

```
var i = rs.initiate({ 
   _id: 'rs0',
   members:[
      { _id: 0, host: 'mongodb1:27017' },
      { _id: 1, host: 'mongodb2:27018' },
      { _id: 2, host: 'mongodb3:27019' }
   ]
});
if (i.ok != 1) {
   print(EJSON.stringify(i)); 
   quit(1);
}
while (! db.hello().isWritablePrimary ) sleep(1000);
```

Run this script in `mongosh` and check the return value `$?`